# Cannot upload .ipa to iTunes using Application Loader

Tags: ios, iphone, upload, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm trying to upload my iPhone .ipa file to `iTunesconnect`. I've done that many times successfully using Application Loader, but lately it takes more and more time. 
This night & morning I'm stuck at max 15% being uploaded, then my home network completely or partially crashes, and I have to start from the beginning, usually with resetting router first.

Some potentially useful data:

1. I'm using Application Loader for updating ipa
2. Application loader uses port 443 for https
3. .ipa file is about 50MB big
4. I've updated java as suggested on one stack overflow thread
5. Firewall is turned off

Comment: xcode version problem i think. beta is not working for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faces a similar problem some time back with Xcode 6, and it was not due to Application Loader, but either my mac or the network. How I resolved the problem was that I used a friend's Mac on a different network and it uploaded smoothly and without any problems. However while trying to fix my problem I came across multiple solutions that may work for you:

1. Use the default Xcode Build submission tool (The one that you get after validating your .ipa file and it says submit to the App Store)
2. Use Application Loader (this only works if you were trying with the Xcode uploader in the first place, however I'm assuming you weren't)
3. Upload from a different network (This seemed to have helped a lot of people.)
4. Use a different mac. Sometimes the issue could be with your machine. (You can try restarting it, but using a second mac if available would be much better.)
5. Use the last stable release of Xcode. When using one of the Beta's, try to use the last official release. (And also make sure you aren't using any pre-release technologies, however this should only stop you at a later stage)

You can try any of the above points, as for me a combination of 3 and 4 worked.

Hope that helps, Julian

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I up voted it, but I will left it unaccepted, hoping to get more answers. I'm having problems again, and to me sounds a bit crazy (this goes to apple, not to you) to need to have two (expensive) machines just to do simple upload. Equally frustrating seams going around looking for other network.

Comment: 1,2,5 didn't help.
I haven't yet tried from other mac(3), because I don't have any other available.
I'm going to try from a different network now(4), although seams crazy that I would have to go around every time I have to do upload. 
If there is no other technical solution with fixing current network, I will accept it as a right solution.

Comment: There probably is, last time I contacted Apple about it they had no clue how togh. Good luck!

Comment: @daneejela Did you manage yet? I may have found a second solution for you.

Comment: Sorry for delayed answer, I just saw your message. 
I managed to upload it back then using other network, although not from the  first try. 
In the meantime I didn't have any uploads, but I will have it soon, so any potential solution I would be happy to try!
Thanks for your time and willingness to help :)

Comment: Glad that you did manage to solve it with the other network after all. What a friend of mine suggested was using a VPN. She said that this worked as good as the different network. Hope that helps

Comment: I've switched to using testfairy for testing scenarios, because apple upload was too much time consuming. I will try VPN solution next time when we will have delivery build. Thank you for your time and help!